# Import table from word file to excel file

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I would like to import the below table from Word file to Excel file using VBA.

Below is the sample of my word table.

[image: Word]
The result will group the table value to the same column in the excel file.

[image: Excel]

I used below script to covert the word table to excel.

```
Sub ImportWordTable()

Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim wdFileName As Variant
Dim tableNo As Integer 'table number in Word
Dim iRow As Long 'row index in Excel
Dim iCol As Integer 'column index in Excel
Dim resultRow As Long
Dim tableStart As Integer
Dim tableTot As Integer

On Error Resume Next

ActiveSheet.Range("A:AZ").ClearContents

wdFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Word files (*.doc),*.doc", , _
"Browse for file containing table to be imported")

If wdFileName = False Then Exit Sub '(user cancelled import file browser)

Set wdDoc = GetObject(wdFileName) 'open Word file

With wdDoc
    tableNo = wdDoc.tables.Count
    tableTot = wdDoc.tables.Count
    If tableNo = 0 Then
        MsgBox "This document contains no tables", _
        vbExclamation, "Import Word Table"
    ElseIf tableNo > 1 Then
        tableNo = InputBox("This Word document contains " & tableNo & " tables." & vbCrLf & _
        "Enter the table to start from", "Import Word Table", "1")
    End If

    resultRow = 4

    For tableStart = 1 To tableTot
        With .tables(tableStart)
            For iRow = 1 To .Rows.Count
                For iCol = 1 To .Columns.Count
                    Cells(resultRow, iCol) = WorksheetFunction.Clean(.cell(iRow, iCol).Range.Text)
                Next iCol
                resultRow = resultRow + 1
            Next iRow
        End With
        resultRow = resultRow + 1
    Next tableStart
End With

End Sub
```

I understand why the results are like that is because of the table in the word file has only one column stored the value with 2 lines, but is it possible to make the result like below? Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has some seriously flawed logic. You prompt the user for the starting table, then never use that value, instead cycling through all tables in the document.

As for the problem itself, simply copying & pasting the Word table will address your concerns. Hence you could replace your entire 'For tableStart = 1 To tableTot' loop with:

```
For tableStart = tableNo To tableTot
    .Tables(tableStart).Borders.Enable = False
    .Tables(tableStart).Range.Copy
    ActiveSheet.Paste Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("A" & resultRow )
    resultRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row).End(xlUp).Row + 1
Next
ActiveSheet.Range("A1:AZ" & resultRow ).UnMerge
```

You may want to add a line or two of code to change the formatting of the content after the last line above, but you won't need the Clean function on any numeric values, as the copy/paste takes care of that.